# MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri) returns null, if Uri points to a file which has been renamed using FileExplorer

Tags: android

`MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri)` returns null. 
 I change the path of some file using FileExplorer app and then Uri points to that file. Uri is absolutely correct.
But, I'm getting null instead of MediaPlayer object from this method.
Any help?

Comment: Do you initialize your `MediaPlayer`??

Comment: MediaPlayer.create(Context, Uri); always creates MediaPlayer object. But, now it is returning null.

Comment: can we see your uri? look this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: This Uri works as this points to a file which was not renamed. uri = content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/143

Comment: This Uri does not work, as this points to a file which was  renamed. content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/139

Comment: where is the code      ??

Comment: Code : MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(),_resourceUri);

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in the past.After renaming that file, just check, whether that file can be opened from outside of your app.

I'm sure, that file cannot be opened.

So, just place a null check and show a Toast to the user.

Comment: Yes, You are right. That file cannot be opened from even outside the app. Means, FileExplorer app that was used to rename that file does something peculiar with the file while renaming.